# How to wait for the axios call to be finished before continuing the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

I have to make a request using axios in order to fetch some data which should be passed as a prop to a React Component.
Following is my render function:

```
render() {
    boards = this.fetchBoardList();

return (
    <div className="app-wrapper">
        // Some HTML code
    </div>
);
}
```

**fetchBoardList** is an **async** function, so it will return a promise. I can attach **then** and **catch** handlers to the return promise but in that case, I would have to put the same HTML code in both of the handlers.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This is not how react is intended to be used. Please take a look at typical error handling in react: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Comment: Put the fetching logic in componentDidMount, and set your state once your promise resolves. This will naturally cause your component to re-render, which can use the state that was set

Comment: @NickParsons But prior to the stage when fetching logic actually runs and fetched the data, the component would render with empty data set from the state. How to avoid that?

Comment: @RahulGusai You cannot avoid it. The data is not there yet.

Comment: @RahulGusai as Bergi pointed out you can't. Usually, you'll do a check to see if the state/data you want to use is defined, and if it is not, display a loading component of some sort, otherwise, it if is defined, display your regular component.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with that snippet of React code.

- The `boards` variable shouldn't be global. You probably want to store the data in `state` using, for example, the `useState` hook.
- I assume you want to fetch the data when the component mounts, and for that end you should use the `useEffect` hook (with a dependency on `boards`)
- You are using `class` in your jsx, which is not valid. You should be using `className`.

The first two points apply to `functional components` only. If you want to use `class components`:

- Create initial state in the constructor. Add a `componentDidMount` function where you await the fetch function call and call `this.setState` with the resulting data.